# Занимаемся ли мы ерундой?

Tags: этимология, недопустимая-метка

Прочитал у Виноградова в "Истории слов", что этимология слова **ерунда** - неясная. По-моему, всё очень просто. Мы ведь **ерундой** "занимаемся"! Чушь - порем, Чепуху - несём. А тут - занимаемся. Этакий маленький ключик к пониманию. Вспомним бедных зубрил в гимназиях и семинариях позапрошлого века! "Еръ, еры, ерь"... Где-то во времена изменения правил использования этих букв и родилось выражение "заниматься ерундой" - то есть, "зубрить еры".
Собственно вопрос: прав ли я? Или, может быть, уже есть какие-то этимологические изыскания помимо Виноградова?

Comment: Это вас просто осенило? В таком случае вероятность вашей правоты очень низкая. Кстати, еры не зубрили. Чего их зубрить-то... Зубрили яти.

Comment: Говоря, что еры не зубрили, вы только подтверждаете мои слова. Чего их зубрить? Заниматься ерундой. :)

Comment: Эх, знали бы вы, сколько раз меня "осеняет" на дню! Допустим, я догадываюсь откуда взялись названия "древляне" и "родимичи". И откуда к нам прилетел Змей Горыныч. И почему я = мы. Но это никому не интересно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**У Черных большая статья на эту тему, вот ее основные положения:**

**1) Это лакейское слово, которое в середине 19 века получает распространение в литературной среде.** Первое употребление в повести Некрасова "Петербургские углы", дано с пояснением: лакейское слово, равнозначное слову "дрянь" (1845).  Уже в 1882 году Чехов говорит: "...ерундистики писать не хочется".

2) **К быту духовенства отношения не имеет.**

3) В 1852 году в словаре отмечено значение **"ерунда – жидкий, безвкусный напиток"**, и.-е. корень er – рыхлый, редкий, жидкий.

Сравнить: буза – хмельной напиток, кавардак – кушанье, эти слова, изменившие свое значение,  попадали в общерусский язык через лакеев, прислугу.

Answer (score 1):

Ерунда произошла от латинского gerunda (то чем порождают). На жаргоне семинаристов XIX века этим словом обозначали причинное место, а как герундой (ерундой) занимались, думаю понятно и без меня.

В современном русском есть слово "герундий"  для обозначения существительных, образованных от глагола.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь подборка наиболее известных этимологических версий:

http://enc-dic.com/fasmer/Erunda-4287.html

Полная статья Лескова в пользу версии происхождения от немецкого выражения hier und da (сюда и туда) - по поводу отбракованного низкосортного мяса в колбасном производстве (в России этим активно занимались немцы):

http://rvb.ru/leskov/01text/vol_11/02articles/232.htm

Эта версия, видимо, и привела к включению слова в Словарь иностранных слов Чудинова (1910).

Comment: У Виноградова написано, что версия Лескова "не выдерживает никакой критики". И правильно, что не выдерживает. Вам знакомо слово "черева"?